# Cannot UPDATE to an .mdb file using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, sql-update

At first I tried this:

```
    string set = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < result.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((fieldtypes[i] == "System.Int32"))
        {
            set += fields[i] + "=" + result[i] + ", ";
        }
        else if (fieldtypes[i] == "System.String")
        {
            set += fields[i] + "='" + result[i] + "', ";
        }
        else if (fieldtypes[i] == "System.Boolean")
        {
            set += fields[i] + "=" + result[i] + ", ";
        }
        else if (fieldtypes[i] == "System.DateTime")
        {
            set += fields[i] + "='#" + System.DateTime.Now + "#', ";
        }
    }
    set = set.Substring(0, set.Length - 2);
    string sql11 = "UPDATE [Contacts] SET " + set + " WHERE pkContactID=" + cKey;
    OleDbCommand myCommand11 = new OleDbCommand(sql11, myConnection);
    myCommand11.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now this WORKED when I omitted the string and datetime conditions so that it only updated the int and boolean. So it has something to do with a syntax error when I try to update a field where the type is a string.

---

Then I heard that you have to use parameters when writing to an .mdb file, so I tried this:

```
        string sql11 = "UPDATE [Contacts] SET ";
        for (int i = 1; i < result.Count; i++)
        {
            sql11 += fields[i] + " = ?, ";
        }
        sql11 = sql11.Substring(0, sql11.Length - 2);
        sql11 += " WHERE pkContactID = " + cKey;
        using (myConnection)
        {
            using (OleDbCommand myCommand11 = new OleDbCommand(sql11, myConnection))
            {
                myCommand11.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                for (int j = 1; j < result.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (fieldtypes[j] == "System.Int32")
                    {
                        myCommand11.Parameters.AddWithValue(fields[j], int.Parse(result[j]));
                    }
                    else if (fieldtypes[j] == "System.String")
                    {
                        myCommand11.Parameters.AddWithValue(fields[j], result[j]);
                    }
                    else if (fieldtypes[j] == "System.Boolean")
                    {
                        myCommand11.Parameters.AddWithValue(fields[j], Boolean.Parse(result[j]));
                    }
                    else if (fieldtypes[j] == "System.DateTime")
                    {
                        myCommand11.Parameters.AddWithValue(fields[j], DateTime.Now);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(sql11);
                myCommand11.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Which did not work either. I don't think the ?'s are being replaced properly.

Anyway, please help me fix it so that I can update properly.

Comment: i don't know what you're trying to do exactly, but right now, you're comparing every J in your array with a String. Regardless or what's between the quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting and Updating data to MDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625569/inserting-and-updating-data-to-mdb)

Comment: OleDBParameters values should be added in the exact order in which they appear in the sql command text

Comment: @Thousand Okay so List<String>fieldtypes is a list of the type of input for each column. I compare fieldtypes[j] to each of it's possible values to determine how I need to update the value. (If it's an integer, I parse the value into an int since all values right now in List<string>fields are strings).

Comment: @Steve the params are added in the exact same order. You can see that when I used both for loops (i and j), I started at i = 1, and used fields[i] and fields[j] so they always match.

Comment: Could you add the result of your string concatenation to your question (that Console.WriteLine(ssql11))

Comment: @Steve Console.WriteLine(ssql11) will output: UPDATE Contacts SET field1 = ?, field2 = ?, ... WHERE pkContactID = 12345... Like I mentioned in the question, .AddWithValue does not seem to change the ?'s into actual values.

Comment: AddWithValue doesn't change the update string. When the OleDB engine parses the string it looks for the first ? and replace it with the value of the first parameter added and so on. That's the reason to have the ? placeholders and the parameter's value in the same order. What is the error message when you ExecuteNonQuery the command?

Comment: @Steve [OleDBException was unhandled: Syntax error in UPDATE statement]

Comment: No many ideas now, one last try. Do you have spaces in fields names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having to mess around with the UPDATE query string for Access, which is easily prone to syntax errors, I just created a DataTable object and SELECTed the row I wanted to UPDATE. I then updated the table via an array of the elements that I wanted to change, then updated the table back to the server using an adapter. This worked out well without me worrying about the syntax! :)

Cheers