# Textinfo Not posting to .mdb file. Not sure why

Tags: asp.net, c#

I am currently stumped on a particular issue which I need your help. I'm having this particular issue with my asp.net website.

For whatever reason when a user is trying to save information from a text box to my .mdb file it's not accepting it. Everything compiles fine and I have quadruple checked all of the ID and string names and everything appears to match with what it should on the table in the .mdb, the .c file, and the aspx.cs pages.

Here is the .aspx page that the information is input on

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName1" runat="server" align="left" Text="First Name: " Width="125px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtfirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtfirstName" ErrorMessage="First Name cannot be empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="lblLastName1" runat="server" Text="Last Name: " Width="125px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtlastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtlastName" ErrorMessage="Last Name cannot be empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />


         <asp:Label ID="lblUserAddress1" runat="server" Text="Street Addres: " Width="125px"></asp:Label>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtstreetAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtstreetAddress"
             ErrorMessage="Address cannot be empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <br />
         <asp:Label ID="lblcity1" runat="server" Text="City: " Width="125px"></asp:Label>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtcity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtcity"
             ErrorMessage="City cannot be empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <br />
         <asp:Label ID="lblstate1" runat="server" Text="State: " Width="125px"></asp:Label>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtstate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtstate"
             ErrorMessage="State cannot be empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <br />
         <asp:Label ID="lblzipCode1" runat="server" Text="Zip Code: " Width="125px"></asp:Label>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtzipCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtzipCode"
             ErrorMessage="Zip Code cannot be empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

here is the info from the .cs page that it is using to save to the .mdb

```
      public static bool Saveneworder(string Database, string firstName, string lastName, string streetAddress, string city, string state, string zipCode )
{

      bool recordSaved;

    // Create a new Oledb Transaction object
    OleDbTransaction myTransaction = null;

     try
    {
        // Create a New Connection Object to the Access Database
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        "Data Source=" + Database);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        string strSQL;

        // set the transaction object and start the transaction
        myTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        command.Transaction = myTransaction;

          strSQL = "Insert into tblOrder " +
        "(firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city, state, zipCode) values ('" +
        firstName + "', '" + lastName + "', '" + streetAddress + "', '" + city + "', '" + state +
        "', '" + zipCode + "')";

          // set the command text of the command object
          command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          command.CommandText = strSQL;
          // Execute the insert statement
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();

          myTransaction.Commit();

          // Close the Database connection
          conn.Close();
          recordSaved = true;
    }

     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         //Rollback the transaction if some failure occurs
         myTransaction.Rollback();

         recordSaved = false;


     }

     return recordSaved;


}
```

Here is the first aspx.cs files that transfers the data from the textboxes to the orderverified page that lists the else statement that the information did not post

```
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (ValidateFields()) //if Validate fields method has returned true
    {
         Session.Add("txtfirstName", txtfirstName.Text);
        Session.Add("txtlastName", txtlastName.Text);
        Session.Add("txtstreetAddress", txtstreetAddress.Text);
        Session.Add("txtcity", txtcity.Text);
        Session.Add("txtstate", txtstate.Text);
        Session.Add("txtzipCode", txtzipCode.Text);


        Server.Transfer("orderverified.aspx");
```

}

and it forwards the information to this aspx.cs file

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //So here we are initializing text property of the textbox "txtVerifiedInfo" after fetching the
    //values from the session object

    txtVerifiedInfo.Text =   Session["txtfirstName"].ToString() +
   "\n" + Session["txtlastName"].ToString() +
   "\n" + Session["txtstreetAddress"].ToString() +
   "\n" + Session["txtcity"].ToString() +
   "\n" + Session["txtstate"].ToString() +
   "\n" + Session["txtzipCode"].ToString() 
                                                  ;

    // Check if the record is successfully saved in the tblOrder Table and prints the appropriate message in the text box txtVerifiedInfo
    if (clsDataLayer.Saveneworder(Server.MapPath("App_Data\\WSC_DB.mdb" ),
    Session["txtfirstName"].ToString(),
    Session["txtlastName"].ToString(),
    Session["txtstreetAddress"].ToString(),
    Session["txtcity"].ToString(),
    Session["txtstate"].ToString(),
    Session["txtzipCode"].ToString()  ))



    {
        txtVerifiedInfo.Text = txtVerifiedInfo.Text +
        "\nThe Order successfully submitted!";

    }
    else
    {
        txtVerifiedInfo.Text = txtVerifiedInfo.Text +
        "\n The order did not save, please return to the previous screen and verify all of your data is correct, thank you.";
    }
```

On the last page - Orderverified.aspx i have a multiline text box  that clearly shows all of the data but it is returning my else statement that it was not able to save to the tblOrder

sorry for posting so much code but I really am stumped on why this isn't saving.

Thank you for reading and for your time

Upon further troubleshooting i have tried excluding everything EXCEPT for the firstName and it still will not post.
 i feel the problem is most likely with the .cs files code that is the sql statement to insert into the tblOrder

Answer (score 0):

I've never used OleDbConnection, but it seems you may need to use .Parameters.AddWithValue().
See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8625614/613575).

Comment: thank you, i will give that a shot, the frustrating part is i used basically this exact code for a differnt form on the site and do not have this issue at all

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out - I couldnt find an issue with any of the code because there wasnt one!! 
I turns out i had the primary key int he .mdb set as a field that i was not inputting to and it was causing  it not to save because it was set to text instead of autonumber and would not let the file save!! thank you for taking a look at it jeremywho